# Spark real time statistical analysis on datasets

Tags: apache-spark, static-analysis, metrics

using spark I've developed a dashboard for a client with an original database of 14 tables with > 26M of total rows. The data was about physical users, parcels, products and web users.
 You can think it like an e-commerce company with also physical stores.

The requirements were:

- made the dashboard multi access
- perform SQL like queries on a fixed subset of fields
- queries should return a web page with ~20 fixed tables of statistical analysis
- not all legal queries can be done on the original db structure, for example we didn't have user's gender, but we can extrapolate it from other data
- metrics should be count differently based on their kind, ex: *gender* should be counted by physical users, *month of invoice* should be counted by number of invoices per year, *site access* should only account web users, ...

The solution I've come up with was merge, deduplicate, pivot and reaggregate all data in a table were only relevant info are stored, with a reduction of number of rows more than 4 times from the original database.

To calculate the metrics, the only approach I've come up with, is getting the rdd from the DF and then use the *aggregate* function to analyze (and count) manually every metric from every single row.

The performance are really poor, like more than a minute to get the metrics from the reduced dataset using an 8 core CPU. With **one** user.

I'm not asking for code, but for documentation, examples, knowledge. I think that I'm missing something and I don't know what is it. I've seen a lot of dashboards performing queries on bigger datasets almost instantly and I don't get how they do this (apart from the computational power).

Thank you

Comment: It is hard to tell for sure with looking at your data and code, but the amount of data, available resources (8 cores, single machine?) and use case (interactive, multiuser environment), don't suggest that Spark is a good fit for the job.

Comment: @zero323 please can you elaborate more? What instrument should I have used instead?

Comment: Your question lacks very important points regarding the Spark performance like memory, the number of partitions etc. That is a smell of few design anti-patterns. As I understood you are trying to use an existing application's database as the data source in Spark for analysis. For me, it sounds like you are in the same mindset of DBMS based querying or regular application development. 26M of rows are not even Big Data. You should understand spark parallelism, shuffling, caching, in-memory storage etc when designing your application. Perhaps your scenario could be a use case for Spark Streaming.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to avoid using the existing db, the reduced table was on a parquet file. Spark streaming was not applicable because of some choices on the infrastructure... Could you address me on some best practices or examples?

Comment: Hi, few tips: 01) Don't think about normalization 02) Avoid unnecessary shuffling 03) Cache computed RDDs when possible 04) Balance available memory as it doesn't evict and recompute always 05) consider options like MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER (or suitable) 06) Don't recompute same for each user query

Comment: Also ... 07) Try to stay with DF rather RDD regarding catalyst optimizer. Note: On the other hand 24M records in 1min is still good. What you need to consider is a generic data model and maintaining computed data set as it is extensible with new data over time. Again sounds perfect use case for Spark Streaming.

Comment: How often does the dataset you are working with change/update?